# call a javascript from a flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you trigger javascript functions from flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174025/how-do-you-trigger-javascript-functions-from-flash)
>
> **Possible Duplicate:** [How do you trigger javascript functions from
>   flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174025/how-do-you-trigger-javascript-functions-from-flash)

Can flash call a javascript?

For example a Button in a flash will call a function ($("div.boxclose").addClass("boxopen").show("slow");) from jQuery library.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AS3, [ExternalInterface.call](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) is what you want.

In the script tag in the html page:

```
function theJSMethod()
{
    $("div.boxclose").addClass("boxopen").show("slow");
}
```

In flash:

```
ExternalInterface.call("theJSMethod");
```

If you are using AS2, you can use [fscommand](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001177.html) to achieve this.

Make sure `allowScriptDomain` in the embedding html code is set appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

External Interface will help you :)

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this SO question: [How do you trigger javascript functions from flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174025/how-do-you-trigger-javascript-functions-from-flash/174034#174034)