# Call javascript function from flash button Flash CS5

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, function, flash-cs5

I'm trying to show a div when someone clicks on the flash button pertaining to certain div.  This is the javascript function I'm trying to have called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show1() {
        document.getElementById(#table1).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

"#table1" is the Div ID that I'm trying to display after the person clicks a button in flash.  I haven't used flash in forever and am struggling finding the answer; it used to be you could just call it by going the getURL route, but that doesn't work any longer.  Does anyone know how I would call that function to show the div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I voted to close: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174025/how-do-you-trigger-javascript-functions-from-flash

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ExternalInterface. Inside of flash just write ExternalInterface.call("show1");

Answer (score 0):

Update AS 3.0 Using ExternalInterface:

for some reason JavaScript doesn't work when tagged `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`.  So, change your html part.

HTML:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function show1(){
      document.getElementById('table1').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Actionscript 3.0:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){ 
     ExternalInterface.call("show1", "param");
});
```

Make sure in the html `'allowScriptAccess'` is set to `'always'` in AC_FL_RUnContent, object param, and embed.

Comment: I could do this, but when I publish the movie, it debugs and completely screws everything up from the getURL function.  Is there a way to allow it within the movie itself?

Comment: which version of actionscript are you using, and when you say screws up from the getURL func what do u mean?

Comment: Here's the code I have tried...

button_17.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 getURL("javascript:show1();");

}

Comment: I also tried the external interface code, but I can't get that to work either.  I'm at a complete loss.